# Red-under line error on 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-support-library, android-appcompat

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispagradle -q dependencies your-app-project:dependenciestcher:0.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:+@aar'
// implementation files('E:/OFFICIAL WORK/Android Projects/EarningStation/libs/mobair-sdk.jar')
implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.12@jar'



implementation 'com.github.mobfox.MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:3.6.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.mobfox:AndroidVideoCache:v2.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.mobfox.MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:MobFox-Android-SDK-AdMob-Adapter:3.6.2'
```

}

Red Under-line error on
 **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'**

I know this question is asked so many time but i didn't find those are helpful.

I have API level of 28 in android studio and latest sdk-version is 26.0.0-alpha1 in appcompat-v7.

If i make change in the version of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' then still the error will be same as now.

I tried all the way that i can, is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous version v7:27.0.1.

Comment: It is the latest version "26.0.0-alpha1" and if  i change the version then still the error not be removed.. i already mentioned that i tried all the way that can be done.

Comment: Have you try deleting that line of code and build your app again. it works sometimes for me.

Comment: yes i have tried but it never works for me...it makes new error.